# Maven: remove "-version-SNAPSHOT" suffix from downloaded dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-war-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I'm using `<finalName>` in `build` section of maven to rename `my-artifact-<project.version>-SNAPSHOT.jar` to `my-artifact.jar`, I see that the resulting artifact is renamed as expected in my target folder but when the same artifact is specified as a dependency in a different module, it downloads it as `my-artifact-<project.version>-SNAPSHOT.jar` in this modules target WEB-INF/lib/. Is there a way to get the renamed version to be downloaded as dependency?

I don't need the version number attached as I'm running maven build in a dockerized build environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are building a war.

Then you can specify the file name of libraries inside the war with `outputFileNameMapping`:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/file-name-mapping.html

Comment: I'm mostly building jars which I need to be downloaded as dependencies without version suffix. Is there a way to achieve this?  'finalName' does not seem to do this.. I dont see anything similar to `outputFileNameMapping ` in maven-jar-plugin

Comment: The thing is that you cannot influence how they will be downloaded, but you can set their name inside a WAR or EAR.

Comment: Is there way to apply this mapping on certain jars inside a war ? I want to apply this format in in-house dependencies and not all 3rd party dependencies.

Comment: I think i can use a regex in place of artifact id to do this. Will try it out. Thank you!